# Uncaught ReferenceError: __VITE_IS_MODERN__ is not defined

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, vite, solana, solana-web3js

I am working with `@solana/web3.js` and `@solana/spl-token` but I am getting error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: __VITE_IS_MODERN__ is not defined
  at modulepreload-polyfill:43:3
```

I am not sure which library is causing this.

My import packages list is here:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react"; 
 import Select from "react-select";
import "vite/modulepreload-polyfill"; 
import {Transaction } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { Connection, PublicKey, Keypair, Transaction} from "@solana/web3.js";
import {Token, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, } from "@solana/spl-token"; 
import bs58 from "bs58";
```

`package.json`:

[image: package.json]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the line

```
import "vite/modulepreload-polyfill";
```

Comment: I;m not really sure what it does, but documentation says I should put it there: https://vitejs.dev/config/#build-polyfillmodulepreload